# Android GCM push notification shows every day

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We have a pretty big issue in our app which is set up to receive GCM push notifications: Without launching a push notification, the app receives a push notification - this happens every day!

I've implemented a GCM Client (and obviously the Server side too) pretty much exactly as stipulated here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive

Here is my `onHandleIntent` function in my `GCMIntentService`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle


            // If it's a regular GCM message (and the user is logged in), do some work.  
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType) && prefsMan.getLoggedIn(this)) {

            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

**What is causing the push notification from appearing every day, without it being launched from the server side?**

Just as a side note, if I could set a bounty on this today already, I would do it, so please - any help will be appreciated, and I'll eventually give some of my rep to anyone who can help me with this issue, as soon as I'm allowed to do this on SO (two days from now).

Comment: What appears in the notification?

Comment: So we launched a push notification as test - something silly like "Thanks for using our app!. That exact text shows up as a push notification EVERY DAY even though it hasn't been triggered from the server side.

Comment: And it's difficult to debug, because I'm not exactly sure what time the notification is launched (I guess I'll add that to message now, just before I call sendNotification). This version of the app is still in Beta so it's not a train smash just yet, but it's urgent to fix it...

Comment: is your server always running, or do you sometimes turn it on locally?

Comment: no it's always running.

Comment: ok, i can't be sure, but it *may* just be a problem with wherever your server is running. Could the function that sends your test notification be called every day for any reason? I have used gcm, and i'm pretty sure the gcm server wouldn't generate messages spontaneously.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have that checked out. Another person set that side up. Thanks! I'll let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69798/discussion-between-marienke-and-vipluv).